# syntax error on MYSQL Date/Time Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

trying to add a sub query that only shows records from the last calendar month.  The column it needs to check is called DateOfCheck and is an auto TimeStamp column.

I have this:

```
$SelectedMonth = "
  select *
  from   Data_Table
  where  DateOfCheck >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 month)
     and DateOfCheck <= date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day)
";
```

and am getting a syntax error when I place it in the main query.

Also I think (I'm a noob) this is just looking at the last month from today, when I need it to look at the last calendar month.

I'll also need a seperate subquery to call for all records in the current Calendar month.

Okay the full query (I'm aware this is probably terribly inefficient code - as I said I'm a total noob who is trying to cobble something together!) is the below, it works fine, until I try to to enter the date subquery above.

```
$Area = $_POST['Area'];
$product = $_POST['Product'];
$AverageScore = ("ROUND(AVG(Score),1)AS 'Avg <br/> Score'");
$AverageAutofails = ("ROUND(AVG(Autofails),1)AS 'Autofails <br/> per Check'");
$ProductTotal = "SELECT (COUNT (CA001Result) from Data_Table WHERE Product ='$product')";




$SelectedMonth = "select * from Data_Table where DateOfCheck >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 month) and DateOfCheck <= date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day)"; 
ECHO $SelectedMonth;

if ($product == "All"){


$CA001 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA001Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA001Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>001'";

$CA002 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA002Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA002Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>002 '";

$CA003 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA002Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA002Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>003 '";

$CA004 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA004Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA004Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>004 '";

$CA005 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA005Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA005Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>005 '";

$CA006 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA006Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA006Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>006 '";

$CA007 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA007Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA007Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>007 '";

$CA008 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA008Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA008Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>008 '";

$CA009 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA009Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA009Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>009 '";

$CA010 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA010Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA010Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>010 '";


$CA011 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA011Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA011Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>011 '";

$CA012 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA012Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA012Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA0<br/>12 '";

$CA013 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA013Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA013Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>013 '";

$CA014 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA014Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA014Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>014 '";

$CA015 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA015Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA015Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>015 '";

$CA016 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA016Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA016Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>016 '";

$CA017 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA017Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA017Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA0<br/>17 '";

$CA018 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA018Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA018Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>018 '";

$CA019 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA019Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA019Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>019 '";

$CA020 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA020Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA020Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>020 '";

$CA021 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA021Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA021Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>021 '";

$CA022 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA022Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA022Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>022 '";

$CA023 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA023Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA023Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>023 '";

$CA024 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA024Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA024Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>024 '";


$CA025 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA025Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA025Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>025 '";

$CA026 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA026Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA026Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>026 '";

$CA027 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA027Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA027Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>027 '";

$CA028 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA028Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA028Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>028 '";

}
else{

$CA001 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA001Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA001Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area' AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>001 '";

$CA002 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA002Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA002Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area' AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>002 '";

$CA003 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA003Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA003Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area' AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>003 '";

$CA004 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA004Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA004Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area' AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>004 '";


$CA005 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA005Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA005Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area' AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>005 '";

$CA006 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA006Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA006Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area' AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>006 '";


$CA007 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA007Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA007Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area' AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>007 '";

$CA008 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA008Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA008Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area' AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>008 '";

$CA009 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA009Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA009Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area' AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>009 '";

$CA010 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA010Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA010Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area' AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>010 '";

$CA011 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA011Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA011Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area' AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>011 '";

$CA012 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA012Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA012Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'),0) as 'CA<br/>012 '";

$CA013 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA013Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA013Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area' AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>013 '";

$CA014 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA014Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA014Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>014 '";

$CA015 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA015Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA015Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>015 '";

$CA016 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA016Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA016Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>016 '";

$CA017 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA017Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA017Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>017 '";

$CA018 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA018Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA018Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>018 '";

$CA019 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA019Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA019Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>019 '";

$CA020 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA020Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA020Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>020 '";

$CA021 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA021Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA021Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>021 '";

$CA022 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA022Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA022Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>022 '";

$CA023 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA023Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA023Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>023 '";

$CA024 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA024Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA024Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>024 '";


$CA025 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA025Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA025Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>025 '";

$CA026 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA026Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA026Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>026 '";

$CA027 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA027Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA027Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>027 '";

$CA028 ="ROUND ((SELECT 100 * SUM(IF(CA028Result='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA028Result) 
FROM Data_Table
WHERE  Area='$Area'AND Product = '$product'),0) as 'CA<br/>028 '";



}

if ($product == "All"){
echo SQLResultTable2(" SELECT $SelectedMonth $CA001, $CA002, $CA003, $CA004, $CA005, $CA006, $CA007, $CA008, $CA009, $CA010, $CA011, $CA012, $CA013, $CA014, $CA015, $CA016, $CA017, $CA018, $CA019, $CA020,$CA021, $CA022, $CA023, $CA024, $CA025, $CA026, $CA027, $CA028 FROM Data_Table WHERE Area='$Area' GROUP BY Area");}
else{
    echo SQLResultTable2("SELECT $SelectedMonth, $CA001, $CA002, $CA003, $CA004, $CA005, $CA006, $CA007, $CA008, $CA009, $CA010, $CA011, $CA012, $CA013, $CA014, $CA015, $CA016, $CA017, $CA018, $CA019, $CA020,$CA021, $CA022, $CA023, $CA024, $CA025, $CA026, $CA027, $CA028 FROM Data_Table WHERE Area='$Area' GROUP BY Area");}

?>
```

Any Help appreciated, Cheers!

Comment: Just a generic syntax error really - 
MySQL ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from Data_Table where DateOfCheck >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 mon' at line 1

Comment: I'd be good to see your whole query, to figure out what's the issue...

Comment: @Chris since this is just your subquery, yes we will need to see the entire query string you are executing.

Comment: As an aside, you can abbreviate your `WHERE` clause by using MySQL's [`BETWEEN ... AND ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator: `WHERE DateOfCheck BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY`

Comment: @hacket@darkajax @eggyal - Here you go, edited above, apologies for the length of it!

Comment: Actually if you could advise how to loop through all those CA00* variables / columns that would be awesome as well.  I'm totally untrained at all this, just trying to work out what I can to get this project working against a deadline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the final query will start with "SELECT SELECT". You assemble it like this:

```
"SELECT $SelectedMonth, $CA001 ..."
```

and `$selectedMonth` starts with:

```
"select * from Data_Table where ..."
```

So you are getting:

```
"SELECT select * from Data_Table where ..."
```

Another issue is that this is the only of your subqueries which selects more than one column, which makes the syntax tougher to integrate into such a massive query. The whole thing should be reworked into a large single SELECT since you are only selecting from one table. Here's a very quick idea (one select, no subqueries):

```
$cols[] = "ROUND(AVG(Score),1)AS 'Avg <br/> Score'";
$cols[] = "ROUND(AVG(Autofails),1)AS 'Autofails <br/> per Check'";
$cols[] = "(COUNT (CA001Result)";

// Note: %03i will format 3 as 003
$columnFormat = "100 * SUM(IF(CA%03iResult='Fail', 1, 0)) / COUNT(CA%03iResult) AS CA%03i";
for($i = 1; $i <=28; $i++) {
  $cols[] = sprintf($columnFormat, $i, $i, $i);
}

$fieldList = implode(', ', $cols);
$sql = "SELECT " . $fieldList;
$sql .= " FROM Data_table WHERE Area='$Area' AND DateOfCheck BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY";
if($product != 'ALL') {
  $sql .= " AND Product = '$product'";
}
$sql .= " GROUP BY Area";
```

**rationale:** The above code, in the simplest terms, does this:

1. Build a PHP array of "columns" to select (`$cols`)
2. assemble those columns (`implode`)
3. tack on your WHERE ad GROUP BY clauses as appropriate via concatenation.

The trickiest part is the sprintf, which is well-explained on [it's php manual page](http://us.php.net/sprintf). Essentially, it parses a string and places a formatted version of a variable inside of it. The `%i` format specifier says "this argument will be an integer". However, with no additional treatment, your column aliases would be 'CA1' instead of 'CA001'. Luckily, sprintf has what we need, `%03i` says "make the int at least 3 digits wide, and pad it with 0 (instead of space)". So, for instance this: `COUNT(CA%03iResult)` when passed 23, will result in `COUNT(CA023Result)`.

It is highly recommended that you consider this course for your script. It is orders-of-magnitude more performant, and far less prone to errors (for example, since your execution forks in two places, you may not immediately notice when you introduce SQL errors in one of the paths (for example, your $product=ALL query in the OP is missing a comma that the other one has, simple oversight but easy to miss if you aren't running automated tests frequently).

Comment: Ah well spotted thank you! I put brackets round the date subquery, however now getting MySQL ERROR: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Yeah, I tested it an and got the same, so I decided it was worth to to clean everything up instead of explain how to wrap the new WHERE clause into the current setup. I've updated my answer with how I would refactor your query. If you don't want to do that, you can probably just add the `AND DateOfCheck BETWEEN...` bit the final assembly near the bottom of your existing query.

Comment: Wow, thanks for taking the time to do that for me man.  However I have just gone with tagging it on the end of the main assembly of the qury - that's working and also I don't even understand the vast majority of what you've written above so if I had to change anything I wouldn't know where to begin. Awesome though, thankyou very much mate.

Comment: I've added some rationale and explanation. I highly recommend you consider it. Let me know if you have any questions :-)

Comment: thanks again mate, will look into it, if work are getting me to do this stuff, they should probably send me on a course or something anyway!  One question - now we've ticked over into  September, the query still seems to be picking up August's figures, I think this because it's going back 1 rolling month from the current day.  I actually need it to identify this / the last calender month, so n ow if I run it, it should only pick up septembers records, not 3rd August - 3rd Septembers records.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your subquery and the last calendar month issue, you can use `date_format(curdate() - interval 1 month,'%Y-%m-01 00:00:00')` to get you the whole last month, like this:

```
select *
  from   Data_Table
  where DateOfCheck between date_format(curdate() - interval 1 month,'%Y-%m-01 00:00:00')
     and date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day)
```